# How to add zero before a decimal point (e.g. from .07 to 0.07) in Latex tables?

Tags: tables

I have exported many Stata tables to Latex. But I later realized I need to add leading zeros before decimals (e.g. .07 to 0.07 or -.07 to -0.07) in the tables. I know how to do this in Stata, but I would rather avoid having to remake dozens of tables in Stata, transfer them to Latex and add my modifications to the format (resizebox, table notes, etc.) for this small change if possible. Is there a solution to this issue in Latex?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell if this is what you want, but the `siunitx` package has a column type `S`, which adds the 0 by default. There are many optional arguments accepted for `S` as well: `S[<options>]`. Consult the [user manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) for details.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S}
.1\\
0.2\\
-.3\\
-0.4
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```